# Running gtm.js script without any cookies and activating them after user agrees to cookies

Tags: cookies, google-tag-manager

Is it possible?

I'm using cookies module in Drupal 9 and I had to force gtm.js to run, which works fine, but this script still generate cookies without user consent

Answer (score 0):

By default Google Tag Manager does not sets cookies. If GTM sets cookies, then only if there are some tags and scripts running through GTM -> then you need to block them within GTM unless user agrees to cookies.

BUT: There is one scenario, where gtm.js sets cookies -> if you are in preview mode.